# Use d3 csv inside a Codesandbox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, codesandbox

I'm trying to create a basic data visualization using D3. As editor I would like to use Codesandbox.

So I create a `data` folder and inside it I put my `dataset.csv` file.
Then, this is my code:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";

const something = d3.csv("./data/dataset.csv").then(function (dataset) {
  console.log(dataset);
});
```

but the result is:

[image]

Why? Is it probably a problem about a server missing?
How can I use `d3.csv` inside a Codesandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is put the csv file inside a public folder:
[image]